# AEM - certain page properties don't render in Sightly HTL

Tags: java, aem, sightly

I am trying to access certain page properties for a certain page using a path defined in a component's dialog.  I am using this in my AEM `PageCard` Class:

```
public Page getPage() {
    return this.getPageManager().getPage(url);
}
```

Inspecting his.getPageManager().getPage(url).getProperties() in the debugger shows all these props.
[image]

But in my page card HTL I have

```
Title: ${PageCard.getPage.title}<br>
Description: ${PageCard.getPage.description}<br>
Teaser Image: ${PageCard.getPage.teaserImage}<br>
lastModifiedBy: ${PageCard.getPage.lastModifiedBy}<br>
baseVersion: ${PageCard.getPage.baseVersion}<br>
teaserHeadline: ${PageCard.getPage.teaserHeadline}
```

But only Title, Description, and lastModifiedBy are rendering:
[image]

How do I get the other fields to work?

Answer (score 0):

The object you are passing to HTL script via `PageCard.getPage` is a https://www.adobe.io/experience-manager/reference-materials/6-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html, it’s not exposing all those properties via getters. Instead you could use `PageCard.page.properties['teaserImage']` and similar to get the data from page properties.